# git: combine different repositories into one repository with different branches

Tags: git, git-branch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to combine two branches from two different repositories in a single repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244695/how-to-combine-two-branches-from-two-different-repositories-in-a-single-reposito)

at the moment, I have different versions of my software for different customers in different git repositories.

Now I want to combine this different repositories into one repository with different branches. How is that possible?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git remote add customer1 <url>
git remote add customer2 <url>
# ...
git fetch --all
git checkout -b customer1 customer1/master
git checkout -b customer2 customer2/master
```

This should create a branch `customerX` for every `master` branch of every `customerX`-remote-repository.