# Git: Merge fork to main repo as a new branch

Tags: git

In git, is it possible to merge the master of a fork to the main repo but only as a new branch? That way nothing really gets replaced and it's easier to go back since it's in a separate branch.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244695/how-to-combine-two-branches-from-two-different-repositories-in-a-single-reposito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to fetch the master branch of the fork to the main repo as a separate branch. For example

```
cd /path/to/master
git fetch /path/to/fork master:fork
```

Comment: Thanks, Kalle! Here's an explanation on how to do it. Since I have both the fork and the main repo locally. I go to `master` of the main repo (not the fork). Create a branch called `mybranch` (don't switch to it). Run `git fetch /path/to/fork master:mybranch`. This gets master of the fork and merges it in `mybranch` in the main repo. Finally, push it `git push origin mybranch`. Again, you are always in the main repo not in the fork.

Comment: @enchance You don't even need to create `mybranch`, as fetch does that automatically. And techically, it's not a merge as you said, it's just a fetch. Fetch doesn't touch working directories or modify the branches at all. It just fetches the objects and creates/modifies the head that points to them. Couldn't understand what the push was for.

Answer (score 1):

#### Push Master to New Refspec

In Git, a branch is just a refspec, so you can push any refspec to any other refspec. For example:

```
git checkout master
git push origin master:copy_of_master
```

Comment: Is *copy_of_master* the branch name in the main repo? I've never encountered using a `:` before. Can you explain what it does?

Comment: @enchance Yes, for your purposes it's just a branch name. You can substitute any branch name you like for it, or specify the full path of the new refspec. See http://git-scm.com/book/ch9-5.html (especially the section on pushing refspecs) for additional details on what refspecs are and how to specify them.

Answer (score 0):

Add the fork as a remote and do `git checkout -b branchname remotename/master` and that's all.