# Merge difference code changes from one repository branch to another repository branch

Tags: git, merge

Can anyone help me with this,

My Folder structure is like this :

```
Repo1 [Repository]
 |- branch1 [branch]

Repo2 [Repository]
 |-branch1 [branch]
```

Now I need to merge file difference changes from `Repo1/branch1` to `Repo2/branch1`

How do I do that. I am using  git [bitbucket] as source control. For GUI I am using sourcetree

Thanks,

krutik

Comment: Mercurial and Git are two different systems. Make up your mind! ;)

Comment: Edited it sorry for that

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/244695/how-to-combine-two-branches-from-two-different-repositories-in-a-single-reposito

Comment: I don't want to add branch from one repo to another instead I have two repository A and B both contain same source code but there are some updates made in repo A that I want to add in repo B. Please note they are two different repository with same branch not two branch in same repository

Comment: Yes, and the question that @MaciejOczko pointed you to covers that case. Add Repo1 as a remote in Repo2, fetch, and merge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy if both "repos" are forks of the same repository. If they are truly different repositories completely, the merge gets a little messy, but is certainly possible.

The basic steps:

```
cd Repo2/branch1
git remote add Repo1 ../Repo1/branch1/.git
git fetch Repo1
git merge Repo1/branch1 --allow-unrelated-histories
```

That should trigger a regular "git merge" scenario. Even if both repos are actually 100% separate, Git will still do the merge, but won't be able to auto merge any differences between files.

Comment: Doesn't this merge in the opposite direction than what the TO wants?

Comment: I suppose it does, however simply swap the "1"s for "2"s in the repository and branch names and you get what the question wants. The pattern is exactly the same.

Comment: I had to add `--allow-unrelated-histories` to my git command to make it work.

Comment: @HollyCummins: updated my answer. When I originally wrote this answer, I don't remember needing that flag. I may have simply forgot, or Git changed a default setting in the 6 years since I posted this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @GregBurghardt. I think it's a change in git behaviour, not your forgetfulness!